# Overriding equals and finding which field was unequal

Tags: java, class, object, overriding, equals

I am overriding equals method of a class to compare two objects since I want to compare all the fields of it. If two objects are unequal, is there a way to find out which of the fields were unequal due to which the objects are unequal?

Comment: If it was possible, how would you want to get notified? All you're doing is invoking `equals(Object)`.

Comment: So I want to make two calls, if the equals return false, try to access what is not equal. At the same time, I don't want to check each field to find out if it is equal or not. Just wondering if there is an existing functionality, else I will modify the method.

Comment: What want you to know: field name or something  else?

Comment: Both, field name and value

Answer (score 2):

You could write a method in the class that returns an object of the same type with either the difference or null for each data member.  Or you can find a library that does it for you.  Try http://javers.org

Comment: Already tried Javers. It is buggy. Did not work properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create class to strore fields information like this (or use `Map`):

```
class FieldsContainer<F,V>{
    private F field;
    private V value;
    public FieldsContainer(F field, V value) {
        this.field = field;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public FieldsContainer(){}
    public F getField() {
        return field;
    }
    public void setField(F field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

and then in equals():

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        ...
        } else if (!field1.equals(other.field1)){
            fieldsContainer=new FieldsContainer("fieldName1", field1);
            return false;
        }
        if (field2 != other.field2){
            fieldsContainer=new FieldsContainer("fieldName2", field2);
            return false;
        }
        fieldsContainer=null;
        return true;
    }
```

and in main:

```
if(!obj1.equals(obj2)){
    fieldsContainer.getField();
    fieldsContainer.getValue();
    //Your stuff
}
```